# Python object deletion

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a[1]
print id(a[1],b)   # out put shows same id.hence both represent same object.
del a[1]           # deleting a[1],both a[1],b have same id,hence both are aliases
print a            # output: [1,3,4,5]
print b            # output: 2
```

Both b,a[1] have same id but deleting one isn't effecting the other.Python reference states that `'del' on a subscription deletes the actual object,not the name object binding`. Output: [1,3,4,5] proves this statement.But how is it possible that 'b' remains unaffected when both `a[0]` and `b` have same id.

**Edit:** The part `'del' on a subscription deletes the actual object,not the name object binding` is not true.The reverse is true. 'del' actually removes the name,object bindings.In case of 'del' on subscription (eg. del a[1]) removes object 2 from the list object and also removes the current `a[1]` binding to `2` and makes `a[1]` bind to `3` instead. Subsequent indexes follow the pattern.

Comment: Assuming you were able to delete the actual object `2`, what would you want `1 + 1` to be?

Comment: @wim, I guess you might expect the same thing that happens when you calculate 1000+1000, a new int object is instantiated.

Comment: a fair point!  now i'm curious whether an actual instance of `2` is necessary to index a list like `a[2]` or `a[1 + 1]` ... is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`del` doesn't delete objects, it deletes **references**.

There is an object which is the integer value `2`. That one single object was referred to by two places; `a[1]` and `b`.

You deleted `a[1]`, so that reference was gone. But that has no effect on the **object** `2`, only on the reference that was in `a[1]`. So the reference accessible through the name `b` still reaches the object `2` just fine.

Even if you `del` all the references, that has no effect on the *object*. Python is a garbage collected language, so it is responsible for noticing when an object is no longer referenced anywhere at all, so that it can reclaim the memory occupied by the object. That will happen some time after the object is no longer reachable.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> CPython uses reference counting to implement it's garbage collection<sup>2</sup>,  which allows us to say that objects will usually be reclaimed as soon as their last reference dies, but that's an implementation detail not part of the language specification. You don't have to understand exactly how Python collects its garbage and shouldn't write programs that depend on it; other Python implementations such as Jython, PyPy, and IronPython do not implement garbage collection this way.

<sup>2</sup> Plus an additional garbage collection mechanism to detect cyclic garbage, which reference counting can't handle.

Comment: I was thinking that if 'del' only deletes the reference,then the list 'a' should be unaffected by 'del a[1]' operation coz there is one more reference, 'b' to the same obj which a[0] represents.But that doesn't seem to be the case,There's a rearrangement in indexing as soon as there is a 'del' on subscription (a[1] here).The list denoted by 'a' gets changed to [1,3,4,5] while the object '2' remains intact refered by 'b'.

Comment: @tez That's what lists do. They are just a linear sequence of references, which can only be identified by their position in the list (rather than by name, which most Python references have). If I have 3 references in some order, and I delete the second one, then I only have 2 references, and the second one is now the one that was previously the third one. That's how they'd work even if deleting really did delete objects.

Comment: @tez I think I misread your confusion at first. `b = a[1]` doesn't set `b` to be a reference to `a[1]`. It figures out whatever object is referred to by `a[1]` at that time, and then makes `b` another reference to the same object. Thereafter the references `b` and `a[1]` have no connection (except that they happen to refer to the same object, but neither reference is aware of that fact and altering one will do nothing to the other).

Comment: Yeah,I see python names are very similar to Java non-primitive types (user defined classes) where variable contains a reference(Hashcode maybe,not sure though) to the actual object.How true do you think is this statement?Do you find any similarity?I would also love to know what a python name actually holds.Is it the address of the object?

Comment: @tez Python objects, like non-primitive objects in Java, are reference types. They indeed behave very similar w.r.t. interaction with variables. That they store addresses is an implementation detail though, it may be anything else. Eric Lippert's [References are not addresses](http://bit.ly/RPbpgn) explained it well, though in the context of C# which adds actual pointers to the mix. Then again, Python has the `ctypes` module which effectively allows pointers, and Java probably has similar extensions (though possibly third party -- MMTK from Jikes RVM?).

Comment: @delnan The link you have provided for 'references vs pointers' is very cool.Thanx for that :)

Comment: @tez The thing to keep in mind is that there are references, and there are objects. The two are different. Local/global variables, attributes of objects, and elements in the primitive containers are all references. References can **only** ever refer to objects, never to references. But you can never store an object directly anywhere, only a reference to it. Reading a reference, in any context whatsoever, *always* fetches the object. Writing to a reference (with an assignment statement) *always* just changes the reference, with no effect on the object.

Comment: @tez Unfortunately for the analysis above, there are the messy combined assignment operators, like `+=`, `*=`, `-=`, etc. `x += y` is sometimes equivalent to `x = x + y` (which is merely rebinding the reference `x`) and sometimes mutating the object referred to by `x` without doing any reference binding. It's not possible to generally tell ahead of time which behaviour `x += y` will do; it depends on the type of `x`.

Comment: So python names always yields objects which they refer except for the case of assignment where a rebinding happens.Right? I've been learning python since a month and this name rebinding seems to a major pitfall for beginners.Thnx for the info @Ben .

Answer (score 6):

`del` merely decrements the reference count for that object. So at after `b = a[1]` the object at `a[1]` has 2 (let's say) references. After delete a[1], it is gone from the `list` and now only has 1 reference, as it's still referenced by `b`. No actual deletion occurs until the ref. count is 0, and then only on a GC cycle.

Comment: `del` deletes references. Reference counts are an internal implementation detail. The statement "`del` merely decrements the reference count for that object`" isn't true of most implementations of Python, only of the most-commonly-used one.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues at work here. First, calling `del` on a list member removes the item from the list, which releases the reference count on the object, but it will not deallocate it since the variable `b` still reference it. You can never deallocate something which you have a reference to.

The second issue to note here is that integer numbers close to zero are actually pooled and are never deallocated. You should normally not have to bother knowing about this though.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same `id` because Python reuses the `id` for small integers, even if you delete these... *This is mentioned in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong):*

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

We can see this behaviour:

```
>>> c = 256
>>> id(c)
140700180101352
>>> del c
>>> d = 256
>>> id(d)
140700180101352 # same as id(c) was

>>> e = 257
>>> id(e)
140700180460152
>>> del e
>>> f = 257
>>> id(f)
140700180460128 # different to id(e) !
```

Comment: I'm comparing id(a[1]) to id(b). Not id(a) ;)